# Response of cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm wondering if it is possible to get a response message when Firebase Cloud Function is executed succesfully.

The case is I'm trying to send an email, but I would like to make sure it is sent and received by the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sendgrid to send emails, as recommended by Firebase (see https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users), you can use Sendgrid's Events Webhooks, see https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/event/#engagement-events and https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/tracking-events/getting-started-event-webhook/.

As explained in the last link above, "SendGrid's Event Webhook will notify **a URL of your choice via HTTP POST** with information about events that occur as SendGrid processes your email. "

You just have to setup an [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) that will be called by Sendgrid for the events of your choice.